# How do I reroute a logged-in user after page access denied at user/login?

Tags: 6, users

My Drupal 6 site has the login form at /user/login. If I'm logged in already and I click it, I'm sent to the Access Denied page (though the login URL stays the same).

I'd like to send such users somewhere else. Anywhere else. /user would be fine. Is there anything I can hook into to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a familiar question ... Here is how I was able to solve it so far (not sure if there are better ways to do so ...):

- within /admin/settings/error-reporting I entered a relative URL like **no_access**
- then I created a no_access page, in which I described what might be causing the problem.

For a sample of such no_access page, visit http://www.inpetto.be/no_access (access allowed by anybody ...). Note bullet nr 2 there ...

Makes sense?

Comment: Thanks, Pierre, both for the answers and the points there. I'm a bit curious about this one, though. My goal is to have a user redirected to a page other than /user/login, if they're already logged in. I am likely misunderstanding your comment, though.